# Inheritance between table and type in Oracle

Tags: oracle

The code:

```
CREATE TABLE CLIENTS_PUBLICS 
OF TYPE CLIENT_PUBLIC 
UNDER CLIENTS
NESTED TABLE Adresse STORE AS ADRESSES
NESTED TABLE Compte_Bancaire STORE AS COMPTES
;
```

The error:

> Error at Command Line:2 Column:8
>   Error report:
>   SQL Error: ORA-00922: missing or invalid option
>   00922. 00000 -  "missing or invalid option"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  You can create a subtype of a type.  You can create a table of a type.  You can't do both in a single operation (and I'm not even sure what end result you'd hope to get).

Comment: thanks, what i'm trying to do is create table "Client_prive" that when i insert to it , automatically insert in "Client" but now i think its need a trigger,

Comment: Is `client_prive` the same as `client_publics`?  That doesn't seem likely.  But your `create table` statement in the question is apparently trying to create a `client_publics` table while your comment is talking about a table with a different name.  Is `clients` an object type that already exists?  Is `clients_public` an object type that already exists?  What is the difference between a `clients` object and a `clients_public` object?  Maybe you want to define a `clients_public` object type and then a table of those objects?

Comment: Any chance you could edit your question and include the additional information as plain text?  Links to images on random, unknown sites are going to be blocked by lots of firewalls and will drastically reduce the number of people able and willing to reply.

Comment: sorry , what i did is create table client (i create the type  client) , then i created table client_prive (of type client_prive) the same for client_public , now what i have to do is total and exclusive inheritance between these tables , so how can i do that?

Comment: So you have three object types, a parent object type and two child object types.  And you have a two child object types that inherit from that parent?  And then you create three separate tables one table per object.  Is that correct?  If you are trying to model "an entity must be exactly one of A or B" relationally, that would normally involve a different approach.

Comment: yes thats correct

Answer (score 0):

> #### ORA-00922 missing or invalid option
>
> **Cause**: An invalid option was specified in defining a column or storage clause. The valid option in specifying a column is NOT NULL to specify that the column cannot contain any NULL values. Only constraints may follow the datatype. Specifying a maximum length on a DATE or LONG datatype also causes this error.
>
> **Action**: Correct the syntax. Remove the erroneous option or length specification from the column or storage specification.

In your case there should not be `TYPE` keyword in `CREATE TABLE` statement.

**Edit**
According to your comments i think you want to create a TYPE `CLIENT` and its subtypes as `CLIENT_PUBLIC` and `CLIENT_PRIV` and Create tables of these subtypes.

```
SQL>create or replace type Client as object(ClientCode Number, Tel varchar2(10), Fax varchar2(10), Email varchar2(50), Region varchar2(20)) NOT FINAL;
/

SQL>Create or replace Client_public UNDER Client (Designation varhcar2(20), Address .....) NOT FINAL;
/

SQL>Create or replace type Client_priv UNDER Client(Nom number, Prenom .....)
/
```

> Note: Use NOT FINAL clause if you want to create more subtypes.

Then

```
Create table tbl_client_public of type client_public;
Create table tbl_client_priv of type client_priv;
```

Comment: you're right i forgot to remove "type", i was asking if it is possible to do 
(create table name of "type" under "table")

Comment: @imed eddines. It means you want to create sub type of Client as Client_public and client_priv. right?

Comment: i did that , but i dont know if it is possible to create inheritance between tables that have already inheritance in types